# Filter sheet, and copy selection onto new sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to filter and then copy the filtered cells in a loop, getting the error message " paste method of worksheet class failed".

It seems to fail because I am using a loop, ive tried other methods of paste special but this doesn't seem to work, please help

```
Sub Split()

Dim wsYes As Worksheet
Set wsYes = Worksheets("YES")

With wsYes

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    myRange.Copy .Cells(1, .Columns.Count) 'copy to far right column
    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(myRange.Rows.Count, 1).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo

    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In myRange



        Dim sName As String
        sName = UCase(MyCell.Value)


        Range("A1").Select
       Selection.AutoFilter
           ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$9").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        sName

        Range("B:B").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Dim wsNew As Worksheet
        Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)) ' creates a new worksheet
        wsYes.Range("B:B").Copy
        With wsNew
            .Name = sName
            .Range("A1").Value = "Column Name"
            .Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
            .Range("A2").Value = sName
            .Range("B1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste


        End With

    Next MyCell

    myRange.Clear

End With



End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: change your `ActiveSheet.Paste` to `Selection.Paste`

Comment: same error. tried this already thanks though!

Comment: Copy just before you paste. Copying data and then doing 5 other things and then attempting to paste will cause these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have Copy and Paste together, not doing other stuff on **wsNew** sheet

```
Sub Split()

Dim wsYes As Worksheet
Set wsYes = Worksheets("YES")

With wsYes

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    myRange.Copy .Cells(1, .Columns.Count) 'copy to far right column
    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(myRange.Rows.Count, 1).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo

    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In myRange

        Dim sName As String
        sName = UCase(MyCell.Value)

        wsYes.Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$9").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sName

        wsYes.Range("B:B").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Dim wsNew As Worksheet
        Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)) ' creates a new worksheet

        With wsNew
            .Name = sName
            .Range("A1").Value = "Column Name"
            .Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
            .Range("A2").Value = sName

            ' moved copy and paste tasks one after the other
             wsYes.Range("B:B").Copy
            .Columns("B:B").Select
             ActiveSheet.Paste
        End With

    Next MyCell
    myRange.Clear

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @BenjiTaylor the copy paste works in the loop. However, I am nost sure what is the result you are looking for ? since you are copying Column B and pasting it to Column B. It would have been easier if you printed a screen-shot of your Excel shhet and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply I have been on holiday, I am trying to achieve what the other solution is currently doing but without failing,

Comment: @BenjiTaylor let me know if you need my assistance with implementing my code

Comment: Hello thanks for the fast response, your solution works, but it leaves each new sheet filtered.

Comment: the data is there but they are all blank because of the filter

Comment: @BenjiTaylor can you add a screen-shot of the result you mentioned above) to this post ?

Comment: The solution works fine already! but the generated worksheets are filtered,

Comment: @BenjiTaylor try the modified code now, the result worksheets are not filtered

Comment: Now it fails earlier, first sheet is left filtered. I have tried multiple things within the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120153/discussion-between-shai-rado-and-benji-taylor).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Sub Split()

Dim MyCell As Range

Dim wsYes As Worksheet
Set wsYes = Worksheets("YES")

With wsYes

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    myRange.Copy .Cells(1, .Columns.Count) 'copy to far right column
    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(myRange.Rows.Count, 1).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo

    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In myRange



        Dim sName As String
        sName = UCase(MyCell.Value)

        With wsYes
            .Range("A1").Select
            .Selection.AutoFilter
            .Range("$A$1:$B$9").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sName

            Dim wsNew As Worksheet
            Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)) ' creates a new worksheet
        End With
        With wsNew
            .Name = sName
            .Range("A1").Value = "Column Name"
            .Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
            .Range("A2").Value = sName
            .Range("B1").Select
            wsYes.Range("B:B").Copy
            ActiveSheet.Paste


        End With

    Next MyCell

    myRange.Clear

End With



End Sub
```

It seems like after making `A1` bold it was clearing a buffer so you had nothing copied.

Comment: I get method or data member not found on      .Selection.AutoFilter

Comment: @BenjiTaylor, remove `.` in front of `Selection`

Comment: error on line above, range class failed. Apologies for the slow reply I have been away on holiday.

Comment: it runs successfully once, and then the loop breaks, completes the loop and then ".Range("A2").select" line.